# Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, input

I'm trying to get the code below to allow me to input Accept or Reject into the console; however on line  "if var userData = fileHandle.availableData{"  I get the error

Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type

```
func input() -> String {
   var fileHandle = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
   println("Accept or Reject")
   if var userData = fileHandle.availableData{
       var userString = NSString(data: userData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       println("You have been \(userString)")
   }
}

input()
```

Comment: The answer in that thread is too vague to help me with this problem.

Comment: That other one is more about optionals as pertains to conditional casting; this question can stand on its own. (Unless there's another question about APIs that return non-optional values and an answer like @i40west's.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is telling you that `userData` has to be of an optional type. But `fileHandle.availableData` returns an `NSData` that is not of an optional type. So you have to make it optional.

(Also, your function is declaring that it returns a `String`, but you’re not returning anything from it. And you can use `let` instead of `var`. And `userString` will be an optional.) So:

```
func input() {
   var fileHandle = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
   println("Accept or Reject")
   if let userData = fileHandle.availableData as NSData? {
       let userString = NSString(data: userData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       println("You have been \(userString!)")
   }
}

input()
```

However, `fileHandle.availableData` actually isn’t failable, which is why you’re getting the error in the first place. The `if var` (or `if let`) construct wants an optional and the function doesn’t return one. So, the entire if test is redundant as it can’t fail. Thus:

```
func input() {
   var fileHandle = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
   println("Accept or Reject")
   let userData = fileHandle.availableData
   let userString = NSString(data: userData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   println("You have been \(userString!)")
}

input()
```

This will, of course, accept any input, including an empty string. Validating the user data (after the `let userString` line) is left as an exercise for the reader.